# How can a php include access the css files

Tags: php, html, css, include

I recently asked a question about my php includes and received the answer. Now that the include accesses the correct file, my html/css/javascript web pages show some hope. The only issue is that the php includes of the pages have this look:

[image: PHP include page (not accessing css)]

Instead of this:

[image: What the page should look like (this page is not using php includes)]

Is there a way for the php includes to access the css files? My current code for one page that contains the includes is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<title> Water Polo, The Best Sport</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<?php
include'../includes/header.php';
?>
<?php
include'../includes/navbar.php';
?>
<div class= "content">
</div>
<?php
include'../includes/footer.php';
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Header.php**

```
<?php echo'<div class ="header">
<h1>The Best Sport</h1>
<h1 class="sitetitle">AllWaterPolo</h1>
<img src ="img/51wmckj8p1l__sx300__1.png" class="wpball" alt="Water Polo Ball" />
<h2 class="homeScreenLink"> <a href ="index.html">Water Polo!</a></h2></div>';>
```

To develop the website I am currently using MAMP and running the code which is in a folder by putting it in htdocs.

I took the header out of the php include and made the css file work with the document, but one thing remains the same. The code that I included in the document via php does not take on the effects of the css document, but the header, which now is out of the include and is written write in the document works. Is there a way to allow the code which has been included via php to access the working css file? If it would facilitate the answering process, I'll post any necessary pictures. Just comment below.

Comment: You need to use absolute paths.

Comment: This is HTML thing, not PHP. Your path is probably wrong, try to use absolute URL. (You can check this by opening source code of your page in browser and click on the link with css)

Comment: If the website is still in development and not yet a live website, can you give me an example of an absolute path or url to get the include working with css? Thanks!

Comment: @sbswim Are you using it without any server? Just .html file with extern .css in your computer? Than it should be ok as it is, but you have to have .css file on the same place as .html with this path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly identified the problem, that the HTML cannot find the CSS. That is directly because of this tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

Specifically, this part of the tag:

```
href="styles.css"
```

You have told your code to look for the `styles.css` file in the same directory as the `index.php` file. Is that correct?

Usually, the web site structure looks like this:

```
public_html
    - css
    - js
    - includes
    - img
```

Your website seems to be structured like this:

```
includes
public_html
```

Imagine yourself inside the `index.php` file. All files that are INCLUDEd become part of `index.php`, as if they were there originally. So, you are expecting to find the CSS file here (as per your `<link rel="stylesheet"` tag):

```
public_html/style.css
```

If they are really inside a CSS folder, then perhaps this will fix it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

---

**Update:**

No need to `echo` out your HTML in PHP, you can literally just do this:

**header.php**

```
<div class ="header">
    <h1>The Best Sport</h1>
    <h1 class="sitetitle">AllWaterPolo</h1>
    <img src ="img/51wmckj8p1l__sx300__1.png" class="wpball" alt="Water Polo Ball" />
    <h2 class="homeScreenLink"> <a href ="index.html">Water Polo!</a></h2>
</div>
```

If the other include files are similar, then it appears your rendered file will all be HTML. Therefore, the next step is: where is your style sheet? Try this. In the `address bar` of your browser, type:

```
localhost/styles.css
```

And see if your stylesheet appears. If not, try this:

```
localhost/css/styles.css
```

If the second one works, then change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

*Note: I might not have your path structure correct. Amend as required.*

Comment: My web structure is exactly as you showed, but the php files I included in the pages of my website seem to not access the link of the css that is already in the header. My home page without includes is perfect and works with the css.

Comment: Can you post the `header` include, please? *Just edit your question, at bottom press Enter twice, type three dashes, press Enter twice more, paste in the header code, and click Save button.* Also, please tell us how you are developing your site - using XAMPP? WAMP/MAMP? HostGator? School account? Or just in a folder on your hard drive?

Comment: Just did check it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot I have another question can you take a look at it. Thanks! @gibberish

Answer (score 0):

Short answer = no.

You may want to look into using SASS.  Besides minifying the css files, you can also set it up so the main (in your case styles.css) pull from several SASS files.  For example you could have the following SASS files: main.scss, header.scss, navbar.scss, & footer.scss.  If your IDE supports SASS, when you save any one of these files it can automatically compile all four into your styles.css file.  Then all you need is to reference that one file and you are set.

http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project

Comment: SASS might be a little more complicated than this poster is ready for, just now. But you might want to mention the main selling points of SASS, such as CSS variables, functions, etc. Perhaps a link to a video demo.

Comment: Great point - thanks!  It did take a while and the setup is very dependent on the IDE being used.  On the other hand, it is totally awesome and worth it once setup correctly.  fusion3k, what IDE are you using?